# Querying data from SQLi - can not reset alarmmanager

Tags: java, android, sqlite, alarmmanager

I query data from SQLi to put in alarm manager after reboot phone like this

```
public class AlarmReset  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    String type_number;
    String op_name;
    String sNotes;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AlarmUtils au = new AlarmUtils();

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.


            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String[] queryColumns = new String[]{DBHelper.COL_DATE,DBHelper.COL_RQCODE , DBHelper.COL_VEHICLE_TYPE, DBHelper.COL_OPTION_NAME};
           cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, queryColumns, null,null,null,null,null);


                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                    au.setAlarm(cursor.getString(0), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), "Test !");

                }

            }
          db.close();

    }

}
```

After reboot I open app again it show error like this.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.max.driver_app.AlarmReset: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.max.driver_app.AlarmReset.onReceive(AlarmReset.java:40)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
```

I think ploblem occor when query database but I recheck code I think the query has no problem. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise `dbHelper` before calling `getWritableDatabase()` or any other method on it.